# Every non-constant closed curve has positive period

Tags: differential-geometry

I want to show that every non-constant closed curve has positive period, but i'm not really sure how to do this.

A smooth curve $r(t): \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is $T$-periodic if $r(t+T)= r(t)$ for some $T \in \mathbb{R}$. The period is the smallest positive number $T$.

Since we are assuming the curve is closed, then it is $T$-periodic for nonzero $T$. Let $T_0$ be the period of $r(t)$. However, i'm not sure what to do from here. I suppose I want to show $T_0$ is positive, but how?

Comment: If $T$ is negative, why don't you just take $-T$ instead?

Comment: @AmiteshDatta We can I think. Isn't what I want to show true by definition? If a curve is closed then it is $T$-periodic. Let $T_0$ be the smallest such $T$. Since $r(t+T_0) = r(t-T_0) = r(t)$,  then every curve has a positive period since if $T_0$ negative, $-T_0$ still works. Is this it?

Comment: How would you argue that given it is $T$ periodic for some $T$ there exists a "smallest" $T_0$ ?

Comment: @user160738 I don't understand your question. There will always exist a $T_0$

Comment: @diffGeoLost Thanks for your comment! Yes, if I interpret the question correctly, then I think that's the point.

Comment: @user160738 I think if there is no smallest $T_0>0$, then the curve must be constant.